# Render Blazor component to static HTML and return it as stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

Is it possible to render blazor component as string so I can render static HTML. I know where is a way
to render MVC view to string. What I need to do is to make a way to create static HTML page that will be downloaded to WPF application where user can then open it in browser?
This is popular answer for MVC app: [How to render an ASP.NET MVC view as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/how-to-render-an-asp-net-mvc-view-as-a-string)
So is there anything similar for Blazor? I don't need to do it in Blazor but web is done in Blazor so it would be nice.

Comment: I believe that `RenderFragment` is what you need, Is this article, helpful? https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/

Comment: I just found out there is library called bUnit but I am not sure is it the best way to do it : https://github.com/egil/bUnit

Comment: bUnit, is for testing. To pass string template to your component you need RenderFragment.

Comment: Yes but it has method to get rendered fragment:   var component = ctx.RenderComponent<SaveButton>();
            var html = component.Markup;

Comment: In Blazor you can convert string, simple string, to HTML via RenderFragment, I don't think that another dependency is needed here.

Comment: I will try it out,definitely

Comment: @StPaulis - ever used a RenderFragment that way?

Comment: Related:; https://stackoverflow.com/q/68889811/1768303

Answer (score 2):

From Blazor .Net 5 RC1 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-release-candidate-1/#blazor-webassembly-prerendering

in your hosting app you can use component tag helper with `render-mode="Static"` or `render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered"`

```
@page "/static-counter"
@namespace Server.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<component type="typeof(Client.Shared.MyComponent)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />
```